# Domain and Tuple relational calculus

Tags: tuples, tuple-relational-calculus

Is there a "real" difference between the above two?
Other than the tiniest minute difference between their syntax?

Comment: [Difference between Relational Algebra and Relational calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32837278/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

The tuple-oriented calculus uses a tuple variables i.e., variable whose only permitted values are tuples of that relation. E.g. QUELThe domain-oriented calculus has domain variables i.e., variables that range over the underlying domains instead of over relation. E.g. ILL, DEDUCE....The tuple-oriented calculus uses a tuple variables i.e., variable whose only permitted values are tuples of that relation. E

Comment: can you provide more links to information about ILL and DEDUCE.  I cannot find any references to them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall they're equally expressive - that is, anything that can be expressed using domain relational algebra can also be expressed using tuple relational calculus.  Some people find DRA easier to interpret...

Answer (score 0):

Domain calculus differs from tuple calculus in the type of variables used in formulas:

Rather than having variables range over tuples, the variables range over single values from domains of attributes.
To form a relation of degree n for a query result, we must have n of these domain variables— one for each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very big conceptual difference between the two.In case of tuple relational calculus ,you operate on each tuples but in case of domain relational calculus ,you deal with each column or attribute.Both methods can be used to get any result.