# How to formulate "at most" in domain relational calculus

Tags: database, relational-database, domain-calculus

How do I formulate "at most" in domain relational calculus?

Example queries:

```
Dish: dish_id, name
Have: dish_id, ing_id
Ingredient: ing_id, name
```

- What are the names of ingredients included in at most two dishes?
- What are the names of ingredients included in at most one dish?

Comment: Don't edit a post to invalidate reasonable posted answers. You have changed the question. Please roll this edit back & make reasonable edits to the 1st version & if you have a different question post that separately. Show how you were able to use what was answered in the earlier Q&A. PS It is not very helpful to just show code, explain what its parts have to do with the question you are asking. PS You asked a vague question so you got a general answer. PS 'formulate "at most"' is still vague. (Show what it has to do with the code you gave.)

Comment: There are times where tiny mnemonic names clarify, and this is one of them. Also please indent code reasonably per syntax & semantics. PS I gave a link to how to compose queries in terms of base & query relation predicates. Another: [Relational algebra for banking scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097). Use them: When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS Again: "There exist at most N ids when/iff NOT there exist N+1 ids."

Comment: "in at most two dishes" You already coded a part like that--"there is no third dish". Exactly 2 was (at least) 2 & not 3.

Comment: `Dish(Ydish_id,Xdname)` & `Dish(Zdish_id,Xdname)` are wrong. `∃ ing_id`s are misused, only 1 ingredient is involved. Nesting is unnecessarily deep, `∃ x (∃ y ( ))` is `∃ x y ( )`. PS A relational calculus is a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational calculus online'. (Ie you can probably give a complete executed one.)

Answer (score 0):

There exist at least N ids
when/iff
there exist N ids.

```
-- there exists (at least) 1 id where p
exists x | p

-- there exist (at least) 2 ids where p
exists x,y | x<>y AND p

-- there exist (at least) 3 ids where p
exists x,y,z | x<>y AND x<>z AND y<>z AND p
```

There exist at most N ids
when/iff
NOT there exist N+1 ids.

```
-- there exist at most 2 things where p
-- NOT there exist (at least) 3 ids where p
NOT (exists x,y,z | x<>y AND x<>z AND y<>z AND p)
```

There exist exactly N ids when/iff
there exist (at least) N ids
and there exist at most N ids.
Which is when/iff
there exist (at least) N ids
and NOT there exists one more id.

PS Be sure to know whether you want at least 1.

PS [Difference between Relational Algebra and Relational Calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841232/3404097)